# Batch - Type text file from path

Tags: batch-file, types, directory

I want my program to display the content of a text file with type, but the text file is in a different directory. So I tried

```
type folder/file.txt
```

and it says the command syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Are you a Unix user? ;-) In Windows the path separator is the backslash, `\ `!

Comment: It works fine with forwards slash as well from my experience.

Comment: Some commands do, but some not, so it is best to just avoid `/` for paths as it also marks options/switches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you cannot simply  use:

```bat
Type "folder\file.txt"
```

If it isn't working are you sure the file has content and exists in that location? *(As you're not using a full path, `folder\file.txt` would have to be relative to the current working directory).*

You could also try the `DPath` command:

```bat
DPath C:\folder
Type file.txt
```

*Usage:*

```bat
   DPATH pathname [;pathname] [;pathname] [;pathname]...
   DPATH
   DPATH ;
pathname : drive letter and/or folder
 ;       : the command 'DPATH ;' will clear the path
```

Answer (score 0):

What I could do is

```
set directory=%cd%
cd folder
type file.txt
cd %directory%
```

but it would be nice to know how if I can somehow precise the directory after type.